# ActiveRecord nullifies non-existing values from request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I work in a classic Rails project which contains its own API for mobile devices.

When I am sending a JSON, with all attributes a model owns to my API, for example a user object with its nested user profile attributes, it works fine.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "email": "user-1@example.com",
  "user_profile_attributes": {
    "display_name": "Awesome user",
    "field_a": "string",
    "field_b": "string"
  }
}
```

When I now remove a field like `field_a` from my JSON request, I would expect that Rails backend will ignore the field when updating a database record, using the `update` method of ActiveRecord. Unfortunately ActiveRecord decides to nullify my missing field instead.

The JSON I am sending without `field_a` looks like that:

```
{
  "email": "user-1@example.com",
  "user_profile_attributes": {
    "display_name": "Awesome user",
    "field_b": "string"
  }
}
```

The `INSERT` in my logfile shows me that the field is set to `NULL` and in my database the field is also set to `NULL` after `update` is called on my `params`.

What I would like to know is if that is the correct behaviour and if this behaves the same in a regular `Rails API only` projects. How could I prevent Rails or ActiveRecord to *not* write `NULL` to fields in the database which are not present in my posted JSON request to the API? Also how can I prevent Rails or ActiveRecord from deleting a nested relation object when its not part of my request JSON? For example if you delete the entire `user_profile_attributes` node, ActiveRecord will delete it.

My update method in my controller looks like this:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @current_user.update(update_user_params)
      format.json { render 'api/app/v1/users/show', status: :ok, locals: { user: @current_user } }
    else
      render json: @current_user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end

def update_user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :email,
    :password,
    user_profile_attributes: [:display_name, :field_a, :field_b]
  )
end
```

For a better code demonstration I've written a sample project with Rails 6 which does the same what I do in my project. It includes also an `openapi.yml` for Pawn, Insomnia or Postman to test the projects API at `/api/app/v1` easily.

The code for the update method I use is at that position on my `users_controller.rb`:
https://github.com/fuxx/update-db-question/blob/master/app/controllers/api/app/v1/users_controller.rb#L16

My sample project is located here on GitHub:
https://github.com/fuxx/update-db-question

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll take a look at the code, but could you also edit your question to include a snippet from the controller? That way if the repository goes away there's something permanent to look at in the future.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. I've added an Rspec test for easier testing.  I will add a snippet too :) 
https://github.com/fuxx/update-db-question/blob/master/spec/requests/users_spec.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile` to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile, update_only: true` in your User model.